# Error when applying patch

Tags: 8

I seem to getting an error when trying to apply a patch and I'm a bit stumped on where I am going wrong if anyone knows that would be fantastic - I need to apply this patch: https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/media_entity_image_thumbnail_problem_2767501_13.patch

I am inside the mysite/public folder where I have placed the patch file and then try to run:

`git apply media_entity_image_thumbnail_problem_2767501_13.patch`

It doesn't seem to do anything so I then run:

```
$ patch -p0 < media_entity_image_thumbnail_problem_2767501_13.patch

can't find file to patch at input line 5
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/src/Plugin/MediaEntity/Type/Image.php b/src/Plugin/MediaEntity/Type/Image.php
|index 09b9655..398d3c0 100644
|--- a/src/Plugin/MediaEntity/Type/Image.php
|+++ b/src/Plugin/MediaEntity/Type/Image.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

it seems to have an isssue with: `@@ -7,6 +7,7 @@ use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime;` should I be placing the patch file somewhere else?

Comment: This is probably a bit off-topic for Drupal Answers. You could probably find an answer about the `-p` argument on Stack Overflow itself. Such. as https://stackoverflow.com/a/2249913/5334703

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The patch needs to be placed inside the `media_entity_image` folder alongside the `media_entity_image.info.yml` file. And then you should be able to execute

```
patch -p0 < media_entity_image_thumbnail_problem_2767501_13.patch
```

without any issue.

**If you are using composer-** I would highly encourage you to use the `cweagans/composer-patches` composer package. Details at https://groups.drupal.org/node/518975

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately it stil gives me the same error if I move the patch to that folder and try to run it from there - I guess i'll have to take a look into the composer-patch package

Comment: @NoDachi are you applying it to the latest dev version?

Comment: @NoSssweat - sorry i'm really new to drupal how would I check this?

Comment: @NoDachi were you able to apply the patch? As suggested by NoSssweat, you may try to apply the patch to the dev version of the module. You can download the dev version from the module's project page on drupal.org. Please note that dev releases are not recommended to be used in production without complete testing.